# Cache using for onclick element on multilang page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making multi-lang index page and I'm making lang change area, when I click each language text it changes.

When I click my language links(AZ, EN, RU) it changes language but after the page reload it doesn't change language.

Mainly I want caching `onclick` functions after a page reload.

Also I want to use pure JavaScript.

**Here is my code:**

```js
var voc = [
            {
              "AZ":"Log in2",
              "EN":"Log in",
              "RU":"Log in3"
            }
          ];


function translate(ele,lng){
 for(var i=0;i<voc.length;i++){
  for(var k in voc[i]){
   if(voc[i][k] == ele.innerText.trim()){
    ele.innerText = voc[i][lng];
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
function translateTo(lng){
var trc = document.getElementsByClassName("trans");
for(var i=0;i<trc.length;i++){
translate(trc[i],lng);
}
}
//add this function to any event button.click,select.change or on load
//translateTo("AR");

function under1(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:underline;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:none";
}

function under2(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:none;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:underline";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:none";
}

function under3(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].style = "text-decoration:none;";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[1].style = "text-decoration:none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[2].style = "text-decoration:underline";
}
```

```css
.langselect a{
text-decoration:none;
}

.langselect a:nth-child(2){
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class='trans'>Log in</span> 
</p>

<p class="langselect">
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("AZ"); under1(); return false;'>AZ</a>
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("EN"); under2(); return false;'>EN</a>
<a href="" class="lang" onclick='translateTo("RU"); under3(); return false;'>RU</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be using a cookie:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    document.cookie = "lang=AU"; //For example. You can choose to add the language whichever way you want.
}
```

And then when the page loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.getCookie = function(name) {
        var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
        if (match) {
            return match[2]
        };
}
```

Courtesy of [@JonathanCamenisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565827/jonathan-camenisch) for the second part of the answer.

Comment: i add this codes my javascript codes but nothing change. can you aplly it my codes and give out?

Comment: @novruzrhmv So you need to get the cookie on load. Edited post now - any better?

Comment: i also adding these codes but now when i click links nothing happen. so other functions looking disable.